# Matching data from 2 pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** Following up from some previous questions, I now have a code that yields 2 dataframes (bid/ask).

**What I am trying to do:** These two dataframes have dates as column headers, identifiers as row index and number values for everything else. I want to match the dates, identifiers, bids and asks and output to txt in a format such as:

```
date 1    identifier 1    bid    ask
date 1    identifier 2    bid    ask
date 1    identifier 3    bid    ask
date 2    identifier 1    bid    ask
date 2    identifier 2    bid    ask
date 2    identifier 4    bid    ask
date 3    identifier 2    bid    ask
date 2    identifier 3    bid    ask
```

and so on.

**Obs1:** Not all dates have values for all identifiers (some are NaN).

**Obs2:** I already tried (in previous versions of my code) to have lists of dataframes or have just two dataframes (bid and ask), but I keep incurring in multiple issues (ex: I get unknown value format or timeouts), so I decided to divide my source files in two sets.

**Problem:** I am not being able to properly match the data (like a vlookup)

**Question1:** What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

**Obs3:** I am currently trying to use the multiindex to create a 3d dataframe with the higher level being the (bid/ask). I also tried using series.map function of the pandas, to do a sort of "vlookup" between the dataframes, but that is not proving very efficient.

**Current code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob, os
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib as mpl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import sys


directory = os.path.join("C:\\","Users\\DGMS\\Desktop\\final 2\\run 1 test")        
dfbid = pd.DataFrame()
dfask = pd.DataFrame()

b = pd.DataFrame()
a = pd.DataFrame()

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):

    for file in files:

        f = os.path.join(root, file)

        wb = load_workbook(f)

        print (f)
        for sheet in wb.worksheets:

            if sheet.title == "Bid":

                a = pd.read_excel(f, "Bid")

                for i in range(1,len(a.columns)):
                    a.columns.values[i] = pd.to_datetime(a.columns.values[i])

                dfbid = pd.concat([dfbid, a])
                print ('bid done')

            elif sheet.title == "Ask":

                b = pd.read_excel(f, "Ask")

                for i in range(1,len(b.columns)):
                    b.columns.values[i] = pd.to_datetime(b.columns.values[i])

                dfask = pd.concat([dfask, b])
                print ('ask done')


parts = {'Bid': dfbid, 'Ask': dfask}

finalresult = pd.concat(parts)
```

This is a snippet of one of my first dataframe (ask):

```
                01/01/2010   02/01/2010   03/01/2010
AT0000383864      160.614       161.1436    161.1532
AT0000385745      109.3122      109.3144    109.3068
AT0000386115      117.7972      118.0388    118.051
AT0000A001X2      119.7004      120.0058    120.031
AT0000A04967      152.8196      153.7868    153.792
```

This is a snippet of one of my second dataframe (bid):

```
                01/01/2010   02/01/2010   03/01/2010
AT0000383864     161.038      161.5676    161.5772
AT0000385745     109.4322     109.4344    109.4268
AT0000386115     118.0202     118.2618    118.274
AT0000A001X2     119.8284     120.1338    120.159
```

What I am trying to get (output to a txt):

```
AT0000383864    01/01/2010    161.038     160.614
AT0000383864    02/01/2010    161.5676    161.1436
AT0000383864    03/01/2010    161.5772    161.1532
AT0000385745    01/01/2010    109.4322    109.3122
```

And so on. Remembering that some identifiers have data for the same dates in both dataframes (bid/ask), some have just for one of them.

Comment: It would useful to post some example output from your two dataframe, as well as an example result you are trying to get.

Comment: Perhaps [this documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) can be of use.

Comment: @James Just added that to the end.

Comment: @Marein I have been trying all forms of concatenate, append and multiindex I could find. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can melt your data frames to unpivot the columns back into rows, then merge the the two data frame using the item and the date.

Here is some prep to assemble the data frames you posted:

```
import pandas as pd

ask_str = '''AT0000383864      160.614       161.1436    161.1532
AT0000385745      109.3122      109.3144    109.3068
AT0000386115      117.7972      118.0388    118.051
AT0000A001X2      119.7004      120.0058    120.031
AT0000A04967      152.8196      153.7868    153.792'''

bid_str = '''AT0000383864     161.038      161.5676    161.5772
AT0000385745     109.4322     109.4344    109.4268
AT0000386115     118.0202     118.2618    118.274
AT0000A001X2     119.8284     120.1338    120.159'''

ask_data = [line.split() for line in ask_str.split('\n')]
bid_data = [line.split() for line in bid_str.split('\n')]

ask_df = pd.DataFrame(ask_data, columns='item 01/01/2010 02/01/2010 03/01/2010'.split())
bid_df = pd.DataFrame(bid_data, columns='item 01/01/2010 02/01/2010 03/01/2010'.split())
```

If we use `pd.melt`, we can take the column headers and turn them into the values of a new column.  As an example, the follow keeps `item` as a column, uses the other column names (the dates) as the values of a new column called `date`, and renames the values column as `ask`:

```
pd.melt(ask_df, id_vars='item', var_name='date', value_name='ask')

#returns:
            item        date       ask
0   AT0000383864  01/01/2010   160.614
1   AT0000385745  01/01/2010  109.3122
2   AT0000386115  01/01/2010  117.7972
3   AT0000A001X2  01/01/2010  119.7004
4   AT0000A04967  01/01/2010  152.8196
5   AT0000383864  02/01/2010  161.1436
6   AT0000385745  02/01/2010  109.3144
7   AT0000386115  02/01/2010  118.0388
8   AT0000A001X2  02/01/2010  120.0058
9   AT0000A04967  02/01/2010  153.7868
10  AT0000383864  03/01/2010  161.1532
11  AT0000385745  03/01/2010  109.3068
12  AT0000386115  03/01/2010   118.051
13  AT0000A001X2  03/01/2010   120.031
14  AT0000A04967  03/01/2010   153.792
```

This is the form of the data we need to join the two data frames.  We melt both of the data frames to unpivot them, then merge them on the appropriate columns.

```
ab_df = pd.merge(pd.melt(ask_df, id_vars='item', var_name='date', value_name='ask'),
                 pd.melt(bid_df, id_vars='item', var_name='date', value_name='bid'),
                 how='inner',
                 on=['item','date'])
```

Now we can sort by the item, then the date

```
ab_df.sort_values(['item', 'date'])
#returns:
            item        date       ask       bid
0   AT0000383864  01/01/2010   160.614   161.038
4   AT0000383864  02/01/2010  161.1436  161.5676
8   AT0000383864  03/01/2010  161.1532  161.5772
1   AT0000385745  01/01/2010  109.3122  109.4322
5   AT0000385745  02/01/2010  109.3144  109.4344
9   AT0000385745  03/01/2010  109.3068  109.4268
2   AT0000386115  01/01/2010  117.7972  118.0202
6   AT0000386115  02/01/2010  118.0388  118.2618
10  AT0000386115  03/01/2010   118.051   118.274
3   AT0000A001X2  01/01/2010  119.7004  119.8284
7   AT0000A001X2  02/01/2010  120.0058  120.1338
11  AT0000A001X2  03/01/2010   120.031   120.159
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Just two questions: does this work considering that part of the date does not match (is different in the two dataframes)? And in the line ask_df = pd.DataFrame(ask_data, columns='item 01/01/2010 02/01/2010 03/01/2010'.split()), do I need to define the column headers one by one? My current data has thousands of those. It is somewhat impractical to write them all.

Comment: Q1: this will ONLY work if the dates and the item ids are same.  If you need to match up rows for different days, you will need to create a new column (possibly derived from the date column) that provides some sort of value that corresponds to how the rows should be match.  Use that instead of the date columns.

Comment: Q2: No, you don't need to assemble the column headers by hand.  This should be handled when you read in the data from Excel.  In this example, I was just showing the steps to copy the mini data frames you had posted.

Comment: for Q1, I understand, I would need some sort of new index to match. Is it aslo possible to use a series map with the Identifiers to to a sort of (vlookup)?. For Q2, in that case, do I just leave that part empty?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean for the first part of the followup.  For Q2, you would not use `pd.DataFrame`, but rather just use the data frames in your code from `pd.read_excel(...)`

Comment: Second part works perfectly now. Now I just have to find a way to do it for the files that do not match. What I meant is, should I use the series.map function or some sort of conditional splicing for that?